# How to check if CAN-SPAM is enabled for specific Account?

Tags: marketing-cloud, community

As per title, Please I need to check whether can spam is enabled or not in my business unit. Where should I go and see this setting?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAN-SPAM isn't a setting, but rather U.S. Federal Standards for sending emails. You are by law required to comply with those regulations and there are some Marketing Cloud features that help or even force you to be compliant with that regulations or at least parts of that regulations.

**"Features" activated by default:**

- You need to identify your messages as either commercial or transactional (this is done via send classifications in Marketing Cloud)
- Header/Footer requirements force you to add certain personalization strings so your company information is contained within an email. This feature can be disabled by support. To check if this has been done try sending an email without physical mailing address, preference center url, etc.

**Related documentation:**

- [CAN-SPAM Compliance](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_can_spam_compliance.htm&type=5)
- [CAN-SPAM Requirements](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_can_spam_requirements.htm&type=5)
- [Trailhead - Follow Legal Compliance Guidelines](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/mr-email-marketing-strategies/mr-ems-follow-legal-compliance-guidelines)
- [Salesforce Blog - Are Your Email Practices Abiding with CAN-SPAM?](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2014/04/are-your-email-practices-abiding-with-can-spam.html)

Comment: thank you, @Markus. I saw under Setting > Company Settings > Account Settings, a HTML Footer with ManageUnsubscription|Unsubscribe etc. If I edit and remove it, I can disable CAN-SPAM by myself without support's need?

Comment: No, I believe for both transactional and commercial you are required to include a preference center at least, unless you talk with support and can provide a good case on why it should be removed.

Comment: Gortonington is right, you need to create a support case for that. If you just edit and remove, it won't be added automatically, however your sends will fail as the presence of these personalization strings is verified at every send.